# how often and when, does Sublime save in its save area?

Tags: sublimetext2

I was running Sublime , I had many files open, some named, some not. Some named had an x symbol near them so they're fine. But some named had a circle next to them.  I know if I closed sublime and opened it, the ones with a circle by them would be fine. But I got a BSOD while sublime was open.

I'd like to know how often and when sublime saves, so as to know whether the unsaved or not yet re-saved files would've survived the bsod.

Answer (score 0):

ST2 only saves when you do so manually. If you quit/etc it will save the changes to memory, however they wont be committed to the file until you do so manually. Personally I like to use the 'save on focus lost' setting, this will save each time you go to any other window (whether in ST2 or otherwise). Here is the code for your settings file if you would like to use it. It has saved me a couple times but there are obvious drawbacks for some.

"save_on_focus_lost": true,